# Clojure gen-class this keyword

Tags: java, clojure, interop, this, gen-class

Is it possible to refer to Java's 'this' keyword from within a gen-class method?

I am trying to implement daredesm's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226064/calling-a-method-when-content-of-clipboard-is-changed), in Clojure. However, when I try to use 'this' in the run function, I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: this in this context."

```
(gen-class
  :name ClipboardListener
  :extends java.lang.Thread
  :implements [java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner]
  :prefix ClipboardListener-
  :methods [[takeOwnership [Transferable] void]])

(def systemClipboard (.getSystemClipboard (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)))

(defn ClipboardListener-run []
  (let [transferable (.getContents systemClipboard this)]
    (.takeOwnership transferable)))

(defn ClipboardListener-lostOwnership [clipboard trasferable] (prn "hit lost"))
(defn ClipboardListener-takeOwnership [transferable] (prn "hit take"))
(defn processClipboard [transferable clipboard] (prn "hit process"))
```

Note: This is my first time generating Java classes in Clojure, so any general feedback/resources is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance methods can take an implicit 'self' arg- as the first argument. So to take your example:

```
(defn ClipboardListener-run [this]
  (let [transferable (.getContents systemClipboard this)]
    (.takeOwnership transferable)))
```

Note the `this` argument :)

Same goes for any instance method, e.g:

```
(defn ClipboardListener-toString [this]
  "override Object#toString with something cool")
```

Have a look at [this](https://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html) (no pun intended) for more info on gen-class.

Also consider `reify` for cases like `Runnable`, `Callable`, e.t.c where you just need to implement a small-ish interface.

Comment: It looks like this works. I had seen this before in other examples, but assumed it was explicitly a part of the method signature in Java, which wasn't an option for me since I was overriding an existing method. Thanks!